# I can't access textView in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm just a beginner at android development and Kotlin. I wrote some easy codes but it did not work much. Can u help me with it?

```
fun degistir(view: View) {
    textView.text = "Hello world"
}
```

I wrote this but I could not access textView. Note: My textView's id is textView too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first you need to set an `id` for the `TextView` in your `XML` file

then in your `onCreate` function in your `Activity` or `Fragment` you will get the `TextView` in your `XML` and assign it to an `Object` like this and set the text after that

```
val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView)
textView.text = "Hello World"
```

For the Kotlin Extensions solution do the following

1- go to your app gradle file and add this plugin

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

2- and now once you write this

```
textView.text = "Hello World"
```

it will show you textView in underlined red and says it can import it, once you do, it will work.
this will bypass the findViewById and you will no longer need it.

Comment: findViewById deprecated !

Comment: Android studio says:  Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in 

fun <T : View!> findViewById
(
id: Int
)
: T!
Please specify it explicitly.

Comment: @kzncrda they did introduce View Binding which is similar to Data Binding, however those are not what i would recommend for a begginer.

Comment: @MahmoudOmara sir, it really worked. Thank you so much. But I want to ask another thing. I'm following a tutorial and in there, instructor just wrote the "textView.text="blabla". Is it not possible to write?

Comment: if you are using Kotlin then this is possible by enabling Kotlin Extensions in your gradle file, what this does is bypass the findViewById line an directly reads the id from your XML file as an import

Comment: i will edit my answer to include the extensions and you should mark it as the solution for others later on

Comment: yes that's it, the check button is the correct solution mark, welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewBinding

module-level `build.gradle` file.

```
    android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
     }
   }
```

---

Usage For example, given a layout file called result_profile.xml:

```
<LinearLayout ... >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/name" />
    <ImageView android:cropToPadding="true" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

Sample OnCreate

To set up an instance of the binding class for use with an activity, perform the following steps in the activity's onCreate() method:

Call the static inflate() method included in the generated binding class. This creates an instance of the binding class for the activity to use.
Get a reference to the root view by either calling the getRoot() method or using Kotlin property syntax.
Pass the root view to setContentView() to make it the active view on the screen.

```
private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
}
```

---

```
binding.textViewId.text = "blablabla"
```

Comment: i don't think it's a good approach to tell someone who had just started with Android development to use data binding, however this will also work but it's just too advanced for begginers

Answer (score 0):

This procedure works for me : Go to build.gradle(Module: -> after dependencies { add these lines: apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' You can watch the video in this link : https://keley-blue-book.blogspot.com/2021/08/kotlin-how-to-get-and-set-text-to.html

Comment: please format your code as code. (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)